# jQuery attr() doesn't support property or method 'replace'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script which works fine in chrome/Firefox but not in IE.

> Object doesn't support property or method 'replace'

I need to replace part of a url and open that link in new tab. Basically it is running behind a secure site and all external links gets that server name in front of that, so I need to replace that with 'http:'

```
$('a[href*="youtube.com"]').attr("href", $('a[href*="youtube.com"]').replace ("https://serverdomain.com/", "http:"))
```

on only IE the above script throwing error.

Comment: "IE the above script throwing error" You really need to share this error.

Comment: @spender it's in the title ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you are attempting to use `replace` on a jQuery object, hence you're getting the `replace is undefined` error. Secondly, [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) can take a function which you can use to return the replaced value more simply. Try this:

```
$('a[href*="youtube.com"]').attr("href", function(i, value) {
    return value.replace("https://serverdomain.com/", "http:");
});
```

I would imagine you also need to change `http:` to `http://` to make sure your URLs remain valid.